# Why do all 3 sites start with S?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-name

Is this because of the **S**tar Wars analogy Jeff pointed out a while ago? Or is it just by coincidence?

Comment: Because Jeff apparently owns a [giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/167443).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's forward thinking on Jeff's part.  Eventually, when the entire thing is sold to Microsoft or Google, it'll be a simple transition to referring to them as $O, $F, and $U.

Answer (score 3):

Coincidence.  There were contests held where users were actually allowed to vote on the names.

Comment: Well there was no formal poll for ServerFault (though Jeff did solicit names), and there was no mention of SuperUser until Jeff bought the domain.

Answer (score 1):

It's because Joel and Jeff really met for the first time back in the Slytherin House, and you know who their mascot was...

Comment: Why do Joel and Jeff start with 'J'? strange stuff

Comment: Actually they don't. BOM BOM BOM!

Answer (score 0):

...Why not?