# New users can't create new tags: show a singular or plural message?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wording, plurals

The same error message is shown if a user (without sufficient rep) tries to add one tag or several:

[image]

Comment: time can be better spent

Comment: Yes it's minor, but the sites will be (very slightly) more humane (especially for new users).

Comment: Hope you like the tumble weed badge.

Comment: I'll vote this up when I get more rep.  Getting singular/plural right is a signifier of quality.

Comment: Jeff spends time fixing extremely minor errors like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10248/small-rendering-problem-with-google-chrome-on-main-page but claims that shoddy English is not important enough to fix? I is very disappointed.

Comment: Oh is you than?

Comment: I hope one day these bug fixed. What about our non-english speaking user

Comment: @AlexAngas: by putting on the site things that piss off English teachers, we provide non-native speakers examples to imitate should they desire to blend into American society.

Answer (score 134):

http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

> ## Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

But not you. I like you. You're nice.

Comment: GET SOME http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S06nIz4scvI

Comment: More bold! I can still read it!

Comment: 1 users don't like this approach, while 3 does.

Comment: How about punctuation errors? There should be a dot after the last "S"... :-)

Comment: These are the days when people hate it that comments cannot be downvoted... ;-)

Comment: There's a reason people keep opening these "bugs"...

Comment: it's because they secretly hate themselves!

Comment: cool, a way to meet Jeff in person.

Comment: There should be a "here comes an 's'" apostrophe before the 's'.

Comment: Jeff, why do you resist our attempts to trick you into becoming a better writer? I mean, we fell for your tricks, after all: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html ;)

Comment: @JeffAtwood Sorry, I just opened another bug, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125711/155190

Comment: No thanks, I'd prefer you bludgeon me with a 'more different S'. And a top mark on a long V.

Comment: And now, thanks to this answer, I will forewer be hunted by an image of Jeff pursuing is victim to hit him on the forehead with a small silverware "S" like in the "[The Horribly Slow Murderer with the Extremely Inefficient Weapon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VDvgL58h_Y)" trailer....

Comment: Waiting for the photo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165244/is-negative-one-plural

Comment: One good thing is that Stack Overflow doesn't ask for the user's address, and if it does, one could simply give it a P.O. box and he would bring the whole post office down...

Comment: A giant S. to kill a small bug? lol

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - No. There is no reason for an apostrophe before a S. An apostrophe is for elision.