# Small rendering problem with Google Chrome on main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, google-chrome, rendering

If question has more than 100k views, question listing has a small rendering error with Google Chrome. Letter "k" is rendered on top of word "views".

Firefox 3.0.x works correctly.

See, for example, [main page](https://stackoverflow.com/) which currently contains question [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

[image]

Comment: What's with the unnecessary bump, yo

Comment: I'll throw my support in for this, too.  I'm seeing the same thing.

Browser: Google Chrome 2.0.172.39
OS: Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2

Comment: I think it's all Webkit browsers - this is in Safari too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been fixed in [in this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views). It is now kviews or mviews.