# Bug with Display of Thousand Views on MSO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views, si-prefix

This has probably been reported already, but still, the k on the number of views for thousands isn't displaying properly:

[alt text http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/9762/picture5me.png](http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/9762/picture5me.png)

Yeah, pretty sure that that's not intentional. The k should probably be on the same line as the 2.

Comment: it's like "kbytes" - they're "kiloviews"

Comment: 2048 views, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is 'by design', but IMHO, the design is not working.

The 'k' should ***definitely*** be on the same line as the '2'<del>, and in upper case</del>.

The current method of using '2 kviews' makes the post look like it only has two votes when you are scanning the page.  It would be much clearer if it said '**2K views**' (with line break between the '2K' and 'views' of course).

Comment: That's how it was originally. However, "100k" was too wide to fit in the spot, so the design needed to be changed. Though it's not great, the "kviews" solution is the best one I've seen suggested.

Comment: The unit prefix kilo is assigned the **lower case** symbol `k`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-

Comment: no, it doesn't -- it's also in a different color. Harder to see here on greyscale meta, but obviously orange-tinted on SO.

Comment: @Stepan202: My bad if I had the incorrect case.  But my point stands - '2k views' is (again, IMHO) much more readable than '2 kviews'.

Comment: @Kyle: Sorry, but I think the design should be adjusted to fit the content, not the other way around.

Comment: I also just noticed that '1000 view' questions are displayed as '2k views' on the main questions pages (as opposed to the front page).  I know I'm nit-picking here, so feel free to start ignoring me, but it seems possible that you do like the '2k view' format better, but didn't want to adjust the design to accomodate this format.

Comment: @Jeff:  'no, it doesn't'.  sorry, what were you referring to here?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is intentional. This is a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views) to accommodate over 100,000 views on a question.