# Use abbreviations for 1000+ score in linked posts

Tags: feature-request, information-display, linked-questions, score, si-prefix

I don't really enjoy the ragged view of linked posts:

[image]

This feature request is to use a format that suggested in [Related questions with over 99 score display incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230534/168244); something that matches the user-profile tags page in terms of the tally:

[image]

That is, use abbreviations for 1000+ (k for 1,000+, m for 1,000,000+, ...).

Comment: *m* stays for *morpfloggles*, by the way. So it should be *M*

Comment: @nicael See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87251/use-m-for-million-instead-of-m).

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, it seems like entries with scores from 1 to 3 digits are aligned.

But with 4-digit scores and 3-digit negative scores, the alignment is broken, as shown below (it's the Related/Linked sidebar of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230534/168244)).

[image: mis-alignment]

Using abbreviation like k = 1000+ won't work for the -157 entry in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good suggestion (I posted [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258445/add-k-suffix-for-question-score-where-appropriate) because I wasn't aware of this one).

I wouldn't go as far as abbreviating for instance 1243 as you seem to suggest. (Reputation is for instance not abbreviated for such small numbers.) I *would* however suggest starting to abbreviate numbers when they reach 10.000 and above.

For example, I'd suggest changing this

[image: With full score visible]

to this:

[image: Score with k suffix]

Answer (score -10):

According to international standards (ISO, SI etc.), the SI prefix symbol k (kilo) must not stand alone; thus, it is wrong to write “1 k” (or even worse “1k”) for “1000”.

Comment: Now the only question that remains is if the site is to adhere to ISO standards in each and every regard or if votes are an SI unit.

Comment: According to the same standards, "k" is always 1000, for 1024 you should use "ki" (for "kibi"): so adherence to those standards has already gone.

Comment: When you're there, the space should be a thin space by the typographical rules, and as a thin space, also non-stretchable. And after all, who in the world cares about ISO on websites? And who in the world cares about ISO but engineers and people who believe that 9001 makes a company better (disclaimer: it does not).