# Add 'k' suffix for question score where appropriate

Tags: feature-request, information-display, score, si-prefix

I suggest using the `k` suffix for question scores where appropriate, just as it is used when displaying for instance reputation, view counts, "people reached" etc.

**Example:** I suggest changing this

[image: With full score visible]

to this:

[image: Score with k suffix]

The fact that the question has a score of *exactly* 10851 isn't really that interesting, and suffixes are used consistency elsewhere on the site.