# Should we use 1000k, 1.0M or 1,000k in a reputation graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph, si-prefix

[image]

Jon Skeet has recently reached enough reputation to make the 1000k label show up in [his reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation). However, I am wondering, should we use 1000k, 1.0M or 1,000k in a reputation graph? Maybe something else?

Comment: Related: [Use abbreviations for 1000+ score in linked posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239654/168244)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd be inclined to leave it, for a few reasons:

- It's using Highcharts, and it's probably hard to adjust the labels anyway (A quick run through the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis) doesn't reveal anything obvious), but the smart developers could probably figure it out if they really wanted to.
- Jon Skeet is just awesome. We should let him break stuff - there's nothing more epic than having a number of imaginary internet points that overflows the y-axis on a chart.