# StackExchange feedback: Shouldn't "3 kviews" be 3K views"?

Tags: feature-request, design, si-prefix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [100 thousand views or more: “thousand” comes below “views”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views)
>   [kviews should be k views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views)

I just noticed on StackExchange UX says 3 kviews (you can observe this by clicking "month" tab on the homepage)

I didn't catch this at first, and found myself focusing instead on the questions with hundreds of views (..."785 views" stands out more than "3 kviews")

Obviously this should be "3K views" instead of "3 kviews"

...What the hell is a kview anyway? A mistake.

Comment: I thin kyou're right

Comment: also (and keep in mind I'm not a UX person) - isn't "k" the technically correct symbol for thousand, not "K"?

Comment: I'll have to dig through those questions sometime... but it really wouldn't hurt to make them 4 characters wide - this would also make room for a 1.2m (1.2 million) view count (hey, it's possible)

Comment: I read it as "kiloviews" in the same was as "kilometers". Though that's probably a rationalisation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [kviews should be k views?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views) (and [Bug with Display of Thousand Views on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28986/bug-with-display-of-thousand-views-on-mso); see also [kviews vs k views; Stack Overflow vs Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43662/kviews-vs-k-views-stack-overflow-vs-stack-exchange))

Comment: K? Never heard about such prefix

Comment: Fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232137/13295