# "kviews" should be "k views"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, views, si-prefix

I just noticed this, and I don't think it used to display this way. It seems to make more sense as "k views". Can we change it (back)?

[image]

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views

Comment: Not a fan of kilowatts or kilometers? What's so wrong about kiloviews?

Comment: ok then. initially thought it was a rendering/spacing issue.

Comment: **I hate 'kviews'.**  Why?  Because I'd like the number value directly comparable to the values above and below it.  Consistent units in the column is a good thing.

Comment: Care to recover the image and use the official upload (to Imgur) to add it again? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with the next build (rev 2014.5.23.2267 here on meta and 2014.5.23.1623 elsewhere):

[image]

P.S. Rest in peace, ["manswers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btm20.png).

Comment: "manswers" - was that really what it would've shown for a question with a million answers? :)

Comment: @Mysticial See my edit. :)

Comment: Oh dear... Talk about future-proofing in case the bike-shed problem never got fixed. :D

Comment: Minor thing, but I thought I'd mention it anyway. It looks like the favorites page is still using kviews. Everything else looks great!

Comment: @Mysticial Whoops, missed that one. Will be fixed in the next build. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

I seem to recall it being more like:

```
   3k
 views
```

which reads better to me than

```
   3
 kviews
```

It's really easy to miss the "kviews" when scanning because it's tiny compared to the number. I prefer the first way.

Comment: The first way breaks down when you get questions with 10s or even 100s of kilo views.

Comment: 10s should be fine. Maybe for 100s we could use the lakh: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: I was just about to ask what are 'kviews'. Now that I read. It's a new measurement? Kiloviews? What the hell are 'kviews' This confuses and angers me!!!

Comment: I am color blind.  I can't find the kviews very easily.  123k seems to make it large and clear, as it should be.

Comment: Aaah, I get it now -- "thousands of views". Obviously, it's not immediately obvious. How do you think I found this thread? :)

Comment: Found this thread in the same way... nfc what 'kviews' meant. I see the "status-bydesign" tag which means "intentional and not subject to correction". Sure it might be intentional but that doesn't mean it can't be subject to correction? I agree '10k views' > '10 kviews'.

Answer (score 10):

I think the k should be adjacent the number, and not part of some new unit.  I've two reasons:

1. The column values should all be of the same units.
2. Consistency with elsewhere in the application, like from the [All Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page

The 'kviews' thing knots up my knickers like you wouldn't believe.  It's like someone took my pony away.  Childish, I know.  But please...make it better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always a fan of standard form

How about **3x10^3** views?

Comment: `3e3` is shorter, and scales well to more than the number of electrons in the universe. :)