# Changing 1 kviews to 1k views

Tags: feature-request, views, si-prefix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [kviews should be k views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views)

I've noticed for a while, when there is a popular question than gets more than 1 thousand views, it shows as 1 kviews. [image]

The Problem I have with this, is that the k in kviews is easy to miss, and I think the question has had only 1 or 2 views, instead of 1 or 2 thousand views. While this isn't a huge deal, I think we would be better off changing it to 1k views to avoid confusion.

Comment: @animuson: Actually not a dupe. That was a [bug], this is a [feature-request]. Plus this one has good arguments.

Comment: @Manishearth: Same difference. If you read the topics, you'd understand that they made this change to solve display issues. Reverting it to the way it used to be would not make any sense.

Comment: @animuson: Aah, just saw the rest of 'em. :/ I say Jeff wields the [status-declined] a bit _too_ harshly :P

Comment: Tags can be fixed. If you want to make [that one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29544/kviews-should-be-k-views) a [meta-tag:feature-request], then go right ahead. You can also add a bounty for fun. If the arguments here are better, you should also consider editing them in. But posting duplicates is not the customary way to get features implemented.

Comment: Whoever cast a reopenvote: rationale please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, its always stood out.

[image]

Then again, that's just me, and *that's* on Physics.SE--where we have a brownish styling for these. Also, the absurdly small number *does* catch your eye (I often notive the kviews without even looking at the count). But you're right, it's indistinct on MSO.

On one hand, we have the "append the prefix to the unit, not the value" SI rule. But nobody gives a hoot about SI. And "kviews" sounds plain silly.

All over the site, we see the `k` stuck to the number. Why not here? Consistency please!:

[image]

And in other places(not related to views)

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

[image]

[image]

**So yes, I say we should make this change. "kviews" is nonsense. If not, at least improve the MSO styling.**

PS: tacking on a "k" wouldn't hurt here either: [image]

Comment: *"But nobody gives a hoot about SI."* Spoken like a true American! wait...

Comment: @TheE technically I _am_ American, born and brought up there. Moved to India few years back. Its hard to continue with my Metric sucks views when the local universe breathes in metric :P .

Comment: Ah, really? I assumed from your age that you were probably born there. That must be a bit of a culture shock. When my friends go to *visit*, they're happy to come back home. Guess they miss our broken measuring system. Or maybe our broken politics. Hard to pick just one!

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Broken politics? Come over here and I'll show you what _broken politics_ really means... ;-) Not really a culture shock, used to visit almost every year anyway. School shock, yes--the educational system here is _completely_ different and more broken than the US (rote learning and whatnot--that was extremely hard to adjust to).