# Please make kvotes stand out a bit more

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, information-display, si-prefix

Here's a crop of a screen shot from the question list on the Meta Stack Overflow front page:

[image: screen shot]

Look at that middle item. How can a question with 44 kviews have only one vote?!

Oh, wait. That's 1 **kvotes**. (I missed the "k".)

Can we make that stand out a bit more? The kviews seem to stand out a bit; why can't the kvotes? Bold? Red? A flashing border? Anything?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We could make them stand out by putting the k with the number, like we do with rep, but limiting the text to fit in the space:

### 1.1k

or

### 10.1k

or

### 101k

and then take the 'k' off of the kvotes or kviews text.

Comment: Indeed, and in response to the sure to come "you lose precision that way because the k takes up a character"; if it was 10k rather than 10.1k would that really make a difference

Comment: It looks like this is what has been done.

Comment: @AlE., nice to see things done, and it only took 17 months.

Comment: Well, not quite that long. It looks like it was addressed in the previous design refresh.

Comment: Here's the answer about the fix: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232137/13295

Answer (score 9):

Questions will really rarely hit the `kvotes` but I agree that they are barely noticeable as they are right now.

I think `kviews` should get the same treatment too since there are always more views than votes.

Comment: There's well over 50 such questions on [so] and at least two here. It's that rarity that calls for different treatment.

Comment: @AI It does, And I agree.

Comment: Agree that views would benefit from the same change