# What does "kviews" mean?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I am looking at my favorited posts and I am wondering what "kviews" means?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means 1000 views. "k" = 1000 (from "kilo"). So 2 kviews = 2000 views.

Related answer also given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14581/100-thousand-views-or-more-thousand-comes-below-views?answertab=votes#tab-top)