# Post not displayed under "Top Answers" in network profile

Tags: support, network-profile, top-answers

My [MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101813/what-does-kviews-mean/101814#101814) does not show up under "Top Answers" in the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/ff451e92-83df-4f01-941c-0d7b18d02fe2). Is it delayed or is that a bug?

Comment: It looks like you deassociated them okay (only your SO shows up on the SE site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your Meta account is [not linked](https://stackexchange.com/users/ff451e92-83df-4f01-941c-0d7b18d02fe2?tab=accounts) to your other accounts.

Go to the accounts tab (underneath the gray autobiography box in the profile), and click on the button to associate your account with the others.

Edit: It looks like your other 3 accounts are listed under your Meta profile, so it may be as simple as de-associating your accounts and re-associating them.

You should then get the association bonus for your Meta account as well.

In the accounts tab, in the bottom left hand corner are the 3 buttons. Click the middle one to clear, and then click that button again to reassociate.

[image]

Comment: @Aziz Sometimes it takes up to a half hour for the association to take.  If it doesn't seem like it's working, try de-associating and re-associating one more time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it worked.