# Are negative numbers singular or plural?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, comments, plurals

When posting a comment, the character count shows "*n* character**s** left", until you hit 1 character remaining - at which point, it switches to the singular.  Fair enough.

But is 0 singular?  Are negative numbers?  Both use the singular phrasing, instead of plural.  This is kind of a discussion point; personally, I'd have plural for any value except for "1 character", but I don't know what you think...

(Admittedly, it's a pretty darn minor point - I don't know how often the 600 character cap is hit, but I can't imagine it happens all that often...)

Comment: Oooooh, a fellow OCDer.

Comment: Voting this up because this kind of stuff drives me batty. >.>

Comment: A great opportunity to promote http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It depends if its `-∞` or `-∞s`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I respectfully refer you here

[New users can't create new tags: show a singular or plural message?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)

Comment: Hey!  I didn't tag it as 'bug'!   I tagged it as 'possible bug'!  There's a difference!  ;)

Answer (score 17):

It is 1 character and -1 character.

It is characters for everything else, including 0 characters.

This is apparently how English "grammar" defines it.

The best explanation of this is at:
[Good question: are fractions and decimals singular or plural?](http://neilwhitfield.wordpress.com/2007/10/31/good-question-are-fractions-and-decimals-singular-or-plural/)

Note this is not necessarily true in other languages.

Comment: For some reason -1 being plural just makes more sense to me :(

Comment: -1 being plural is the mathematical definition, but not the grammatical definition. Being programmers, we all tend to sway to the mathematical.

Comment: weird, i've never heard of -1 being singular.  I would always say "negative one characters"

Comment: [Is -1 singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/is-1-singular-or-plural) on English.SE. (Disclosure: I have an answer there preferring -1 being plural. :p)

Answer (score 5):

Time for some `Math.abs()`!

#### Clarity:

```
var plurality = (Math.abs(-8) == 1) ? "character" : "characters" ;
```

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Too esoteric? :) Just a suggestion to find the absolute value, and base plurality off of it.

Comment: Starts to make sense now, but it didn't with revisions 1-5

Comment: Yeah; it was working inside my head...not as clearly when I put it out on the intarwebs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a very minor point. We should just make it "character(s) left" so we don't have to worry about figuring out when to start switching up the plurality.

Comment: No!  We should do it correctly.  Speaking as a pedant, I am furious about this.  I never noticed it before, but since it's been pointed out, I'll never be able to ignore it.

Comment: Kind of silly that they even implemented this feature in the first place since it only works if the value is 1. Waste of time ftw.

Answer (score 0):

It now says "-8 characters left".

Comment: This post has -1 votes.