# "viewed 1 times"

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, plurals

When a post is first created, it says "viewed
1 times" in the sidebar. This should say "viewed 1 **time**".

Comment: Greasemonkey if you don't like it.

Comment: so view it more than once

Comment: Here it now says "asked 1 month ago". It should say "asked 1 months ago". :)

Comment: This should have been tagged as no-repro for maximum comedic effect.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "viewed 1 time's" anyway? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Greengrocers.27_apostrophes

Comment: I vote we get rid of all plural word forms (or, conversely, all singular forms) in the English language, thereby eliminating a huge amount of busy work for programmers world-wide... while we are at it, let's have everyone switch to English so we don't need to internationalize at all.

Comment: Ah, yet another [closed-because-I-can't-be-bothered-to-fix-it] bug...

Comment: Why don't you just use a Regex to fix it?

Comment: @Software Monkey - according to your own answer, you want everyone to switch to *American*, not English.

Comment: @Mark: I didn't stipulate *which* form of English - I am a Kiwi, who works in the US, so I could go either way.  Currently I use the form that works best for my larger audience, which is the US.

Comment: @Mark: As a side note, this whole attitude of "American" is not "English" is a little bit of BS, and is condescending to Americans - Americans are people too, you know.  Besides, their spelling and pronuciation *as a whole* is far more consistent than ours (where ours includes the UK, AU and NZ, all of which I have extensive first-hand experience with).

Comment: @Software Monkey - maybe we need a timeout. My comments were not meant to offend (so I'm sorry if they offended you) but to clarify. Probably calling it **US English** is better than American.

Comment: @Bruno: Now it's saying "1 year ago".

Comment: I hope this is not on http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're not happy with "viewed 1 times", and settle for "viewed 1 time", you've already lost the battle, because it should be "viewed once", obviously.

Comment: Got to appreciate the fact that the OP is now "deleted". That obviously was not a joke threat.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski - and hence, "view naught", "viewed twice" and "viewed thrice"... ;-) Not sure what happens at 4 and above. Nothing I guess.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You're in luck, as [Jeff Atwood has so eloquently put this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694):

> ## Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant [S](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Answer (score 83):

Jeff should rewrite Stack Overflow in Ruby on Rails. It has a .pluralize method that can handle this kind of problem.

Comment: That's one heck of a good reason to throw away everything Jeff accomplished so far using ASP.MVC :P

Comment: Um...I think it was a joke there, Pops.

Comment: I think Pops recognized that - he had an emoticon at the end. Unlike the people who downvoted my answer.

Comment: Obviously that's a bad approach. The correct approach is to expose the pluralize method as a webservice and call it from the ASP.net MVC code to do the pluralization. That approach is called SOA and highly popular with MBA-type people, so it has to be good!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/Inflector.cs

Comment: You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Answer (score 43):

Well ... I was busy refactoring the tag wiki page and decided to fix this bug.

For the record:

```
<b>@wiki.ViewCount.Pluralize("time")</b>
```

Enjoy

Comment: Watch out for giant S's in the near future. I fear for your safety.

Comment: While that function seems like a cool idea I'm sure you will regret it when and if you will add localization support =p

Comment: @Koper amongst another 10,000 things I will regret :)

Comment: @nhinkle It's only for people *filing* pluralization bugs. People fixing them are probably in the clear.

Answer (score 18):

In that case, perhaps it should be:

```
viewed 1 times [sic]
```

You could probably write a greasemonkey script to implement it.

Comment: Was about to point that typo out, but you caught it before I could get the comment off... ;)

Comment: Yeah, funny how the fingers insisted on typing the right thing, even when the brain was trying to deliberately type the wrong thing...

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: You need 2 sic's there now.  `viewed 1 time [sic][sic]`

Answer (score 8):

Well, between then and now, somebody "fixed" this.

[image: 1 time]

Although a bit of history is lost because of this, it's actually correct, because in the song "Killing me softly" by The Fugees, Wyclef Jean says "One time, two time**s**" [in the chorus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKOtzIo-uYw#t=88s). So, we know it is correct.

Comment: See the [answer given by Waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119416/140449).

Comment: Our apologies, we'll try and get this broken again ASAP.

Comment: @NickCraver [You guys work fast...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JtU89.png)