# Small formatting quirk that bothers me

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, plurals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“viewed 1 times”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

Call me crazy but on a question's view if there is only one view, it states '1 views'. I have no idea why, but that really bothers me.

I do not think that it would be a big/hard change to make, simply add a line or two of code before the text is displayed:

```
viewSuffix = numOfViews == 1 ? "time" : "times";
var viewDisplay = string.Format("{0} {1}", numOfViews, viewSuffix);
```

Does this sort of thing bother anyone else? It seems like I am a minority on stuff like this, as I see the same 'mistake' on other websites/counters.

Cheers!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: fair enough. my searching sucks apparently. please close this question.

Comment: Why? Let's see how far we can go with Jeff's sanity ;-) Also, you can just delete the question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683

Comment: @Anders don't feel bad, it's not your searching that sucks, it's the site's searching that sucks.

Comment: @Kip: google didn't cut it either: http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=%221+views%22+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @balpha: Deleting duplicate questions is not one with the SOFU way.

Comment: @Eric: should we expect a new "meta question": The Zen of Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 10):

http://explore.twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

> ## [Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug',](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/133674/anders) [I will personally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) come to your house and [bludgeon you to death with a giant S](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)

Comment: Why do you keep doing this smeagol? Arbitrary numbers are there for the pickings!

Comment: This way I can have an excuse for not having a big arbitrary number :)

Comment: Nuts to thats, your olds stuffs is viables for the upvotes.

Comment: @random: that was awesome. You just had to give me 10 arbitrary points, didn't you?

Comment: Oh, the huge manatee of it all!

Comment: @random: are you stalking me?

Comment: If so, I'm flattered :) random people generaly ignore me

Comment: With a "giant S" ? Where does one get one of those ?

Comment: @Idigas: I'm pretty sure there is a Greasemonkey script for that

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, how long is any question going to be at ONE VIEW?

C'mon! You're not even *trying* to file bugs when you file this stuff! :P