# Fix spelling in user profile: "1 questions"

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, profile-page, plurals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“viewed 1 times”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

> 1 Question**s**

can be listed in a user profile. So,

```
If i = 1 Then
  "Question"
Else
  "Questions"
End IF
```

Comment: Oh dear, the wrath you have brought upon yourself...

Comment: Plurals you say? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/please-hurting/

Comment: +1 for looking death in the eye

Comment: Definitely leaving this for Jeff to see.

Comment: Considering there are no plans to localize the site, I don't see why this (and other examples) weren't coded in originally.

Comment: We should have a single questions where all the problem plurals are listed - a master list to be used in the event that Jeff sees the error of his ways on a programming website, given that programmers are pedantically picky peoples.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I gained 20 rep for an answer on the duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate: ["viewed 1 times"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119416/162511) has been fixed but "1 questions" has not.

Comment: @Hugo It has been fixed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oCQ0B.png.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Good stuff, fixed on site-specific profile pages, but still unfixed on the accounts page. For example, [this](http://stackexchange.com/users/374134/hugo?tab=accounts) has "1 questions" and "1 answers".

Comment: @Hugo That's a completely different page than reported here. :) Come to think of it, it's possible that Accounts page didn't even exist when this bug report was posted. If you feel strongly about it, toss up a new post. Be prepared for [the MSO meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/155160).

Answer (score 30):

Orthograph be warned / A story's told by elders / Which does not end well.

[image: unknown (yahoo) -- last seen: yes -- He complained one times too often]

Comment: Should be "one *time*". You've added an extra `s`. Which is ironic, as the question is about plurals.

Comment: @Kobi: I am impressed by your attentiveness.

Comment: @balpha just interested, I've seen some other 3D creations of yours.. What do you use to make them? Thanks!

Comment: @Manishearth http://www.blender.org/

Comment: @balpha Oh right, I've heard of this from a friend before! Thanks!

Comment: [Burma-Shave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma-Shave)

Answer (score 27):

[image: S]

Comment: You didn't go to his house and bludgeon him with it. I'm sad now. (No offense, @serhio!)

Comment: Alternative text for the image: `S`

Comment: Why upside down?

Comment: [Context](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) (*Pluralization Bug*, from *[The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478)*).