# "Possible duplicate" link block not separate from blockquote at start of question

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

When a question starting with a blockquote gets closed as a dupe, the automatically inserted  "Possible duplicate(s)" block and the original quote block end up as one.

I suggest adding an additional empty (or not) comment to the auto-insert:

```
> **Possible Duplicate:**  
> [“viewed 1 times”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)  

<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->

> 1 Questions
```

Example:
[Fix spelling in user profile: "1 questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/spell-fix-in-user-profile-1-questions-closed)

Comment: +1 Nice catch. (asdlfkjsdfksadf 1 char under min length)

Comment: @Jon - just add a few code blocks with spaces to lengthen the comment without having to add visible characters.

Answer (score 1):

How about a nice separator

---

...like we used to do, before this was automatic...

Comment: separators are really, really ugly -- but mostly unnecessary. Learn to love the white space, like His High Holy Tufte intended