# 1 questions asked. 1 badges etc

Tags: bug, profile-page, plurals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“viewed 1 times”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

If you main screen turn on (look at my profile), you'll no doubt see that I have asked 1 questions. What you say? 1 question **s**?  Plural?  Somebody set us up the bomb?

For great justice, any chance such a fundamental error can be corrected?

It seems (in my humble opinion) a bit of a lazy coding error, and particularly irksome on what is **the** site for programmers and IT gurus in general.  Please fix this, you have no chance to survive - make your time.

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times

Comment: Dear people casting close votes, how the hell is this question an **exact duplicate** of a ***DIFFERENT*** pluralization bug?

Comment: @Kop: Did you read the accepted answer in 20683?

Comment: @Jon: and why is that related? The fact that Jeff doesn't like - for some reason - to fix these bugs doesn't make this a duplicate of another bug

Comment: @Kop - it's related because it's a pluralization issue, and Jeff has said he won't fix pluralization issues.  I can't believe I had to write that.

Comment: @Kop: It isn't exactly, but the answer to this question is the answer to that question. So given the available close reasons, this question should reference the other one.

Comment: @Jon: yes, it should reference it, and it does: see your first comment. I still don't understand what closing this as an **exact duplicate** has anything to do with referencing another question. You all seem to read "exact duplicate" as "loosely related" or "see this other question".

Comment: @Kop: It's the same problem in a different part of the system (which is well-known). This question is *tightly* related to the other one. Not exactly related, but very *very* tightly related.

Comment: @Kop: "This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question."  The "ground" here is SO UI text pluralization - Jeff's/random's answer broadened the scope thus.  Although I didn't vote to close (I don't have the rep on MSO), I probably would.

Comment: @kop we *may* fix pluralization issues. We also also *may* visit your home and "deliver" the missing esses .. personally. Just kidding! I think!

Comment: This is not a duplicate: ["viewed 1 times"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119416/162511) has been fixed but "1 questions" has not.