# Wrong pluralization on accounts tab of user profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, plurals

Under `accounts` tab of a user's profile, words *questions* and *answers* are used even when count is 1. For live example, you can go to my profile & click `accounts` tab. Scroll down to *Drupal Answers* row where you can find "1 answers" which should be "1 answer". Or, scroll down to *Server Fault* row to see both "1 questions" and "1 answers".
[image: Stack Exchange Grammatical Error]
[image: Stack Exchange Grammatical Error]
[Page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577898/sachin-shekhar?tab=accounts)
[Page on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/281536/sachin-shekhar?tab=accounts)

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typo/bug: “1 Questions” on user page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73776/typo-bug-1-questions-on-user-page), [1 questions asked. 1 badges etc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44357/1-questions-asked-1-badges-etc), [“viewed 1 times”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times), [spell fix in user profile: 1 questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/spell-fix-in-user-profile-1-questions)

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGHHH

Comment: This is one place where I feel the pluralization strategy is fine - and I just got finished sending another one to our esteemed Aussie to fix.

Comment: @JeffAtwood There has been a few like this hasn't there? (One by me also ;P)

Comment: @JarrodDixon Same pluralization is correct on summary tab. In past, `1 Times` has been corrected to `1 Time`. Then, why is this one `status-bydesign`?

Comment: To me, the identifying text beneath each stat in the *table* acts as a header - the only reason it isn't a header cell is because there're 80+ sites in our network now and it's impractical to scroll back to the top to see what is in each column.

Comment: Now I'm going to see if header cells with a fixed position would look good and remove all the duplicated text completely - nothing to properly pluralize then!

Answer (score 18):

This is not a bug.

It's actually a clever feature designed to encourage people with obsessive-compulsive tendencies who are bothered by this sort of thing to **contribute more content to the site**.

If you ask another question and post another answer, the problem goes away. It's not the developers who are at fault here, **it's you**!

Comment: If it is, go here: http://serverfault.com/users/71823/sachin-shekhar . Here, you can find words "1 Question" & "1 Answer". Why is that?

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is an absolute lie!

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - take a look at this: [Incorrect use of the plural form (“one questions/answers”)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260613/incorrect-use-of-the-plural-form-one-questions-answers). In particular, the comment from rene. Thx.