# There is 1 Answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, plurals

[image: 1 Answers]

Why is there 1 answers?  There should be 1 answer.

This is the mobile Stack Exchange app for iOS

Comment: *beats @TheWobbuffet with giant S*

Comment: Obligatory: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @Bart I've posted lots of pluralization bugs in my time.

Comment: You should emphasize that you're talking about the label at the bottom (incorrect) and not the tab at the top (correct). I hear freehand red circles are good for that.

Comment: @animuson Gah!!! I'm on me phone!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong pluralization on accounts tab of user profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125683/wrong-pluralization-on-accounts-tab-of-user-profile)

Comment: @Wooble no it's not a dupe. This one here is about the iOS app, not the desktop site.

Comment: Fair enough... apparently they actually care about fixing pluralization bugs in the apps.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236746/162511

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix will be available in appstore version 1.0.2 and beta version 1.0.1.72.

Comment: And beta channel? :)

Comment: Hey, you forgot about it on the stackexchange.com domain! Will you fix that??

Comment: @mindstormsboi The app is no longer supported.

Comment: @Mast I know that, I'm talking about *the website.* This fix hasn't been applied to the website, and I'm on PC.

Comment: @mindstormsboi That would be a different bug, you may want to either find the appropriate bug report with that or file a new one.