# Missing plural/singular on the newest question page: "1 views"

Tags: bug, questions, plurals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“viewed 1 times”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

A minor bug: on the newest question page at least (maybe in other places too), you can see "1 views" beside a question.  For other statistics, singular/plural is handled fine, i.e. it shows "1 vote" and "1 answer".

Comment: Congratulations, you hit a meme! :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times

Comment: The Atwood is becoming angry...

Comment: Oh no you didn't...