# Indicate accepted answers in user's per-tag pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

When viewing a list of a user's answers per-tag `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:nnn+[tag]` - for example, from a users profile page, there's no indication of whether the answers are accepted or not:

[image]

How about a dash of color to show this?

[image]

(It is possible to refine these 'searches' using isaccepted:1 to get a list of just the accepted answers already.)

Comment: Whoa... Whoa whoa whoa! I DEMAND TO KNOW WHICH DEV WAS OFF-TASK FIXING [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)!

Comment: fixing this is a nightmare, that stats arrow is in our sprites, which means we would have to update sprites on all the sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm marking this as completed, there is a slight I did not update the little sprite, but did make the box show up in the accepted answer style.

(fixed in next deploy)