# Incorrect grammar in /review

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, plurals

Browsing https://superuser.com/review and the right hand side I saw this:

> You have edited a total of 1 posts (1% done).

Now I may not be great at grammar but I believe this is incorrect, it should be something like:

> You have edited 1 post (1% done).

Comment: It would still be "edited", no matter how many posts you have edited. So this is a pluralization bug, plain and simple.

Comment: @CodyGray Are sorry, missed the -ed, also does that mean Jeff Atwood will come and kill me?

Comment: @Benny yes, with a giant S of course. ;)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I should get into hiding now :)

Comment: Or get yourself O shield made of diamond. :)

Comment: Oops!  Accidentally voted to close (do not mouse while drunk).  Note that [**the alleged duplicate has been fixed!**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119416/148310)  (Despite Jeff's menacing words)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK I fixed this bugs... enjoys

Comment: to be deployed later

Comment: "this bugs" was ironic, right? :)