# "1 comments" on Blog Overflow

Tags: bug, comments, plurals, blog-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“viewed 1 times”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

[On Blog Overflow](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/how-to-experiment-with-a-dish-what-i-learned-this-shavuot/):

> [image: 1 comments]

Can the script check for the number of comments and output a plural or singular as appropriate?

Comment: Obligatory: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: Might be a Wordpress thing?

Comment: @AnnaLear, yikes.

Comment: Yup, I would be scared of Jeff too :P

Comment: That particular pluralization bugs is really annoying.  We should take some cues from [this blog](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/).

Comment: @WesleyMurch actually they've started fixing pluralization errors (for a long time)

Comment: @BenBrocka: OK good to know, thanks. I didn't realize, and I avoid the situation altogether in my work via stuff like "`Comments (1)`". I'll put the giant "S" away from now on.

Comment: @Ben Brocka: WordPress is able to handle pluralization. In fact, the function that outputs comment counts lets you specify a singular string. This looks like an oversight more than anything.