# Please add suggested edit rejection reasons to SEDE

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, data-explorer

The `SuggestedEditVotes` table on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) only records whether the vote was an approval (`VoteTypeId = 2`) or a rejection (`VoteTypeId = 3`). Please add the rejection reason as well.

This would be useful for statistics such as requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137227/make-the-vandalism-rejection-reason-more-applicable/137361#comment384069_137227).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This data baecame available in 2014 as shown in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202236/susggested-edit-rejections-and-subreasons).

```
select name
, count(*)
from reviewtaskResults rt
inner join reviewrejectionreasons re 
        on rt.RejectionReasonId = re.id
where rt.reviewtaskResulttypeid = 3  -- reject
group by name
```

Using a somewhat laborious [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202283/rejected-edit-reasons-over-time#graph) would give this insight:
[image: A work of art]