# Add rejection reason for suggested edits: "worse quality"

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

Often when I review suggested edits, I see edits that make the post worse. Typically they worsen the format (adding stuff in bold which makes no sense, putting things that aren't code in code tags, etc.), introduce new spelling mistakes, etc.

When rejecting these edits, I'm left with two choices: Either check 'vandalism' (which in most of the cases isn't appropriate), or write a custom rejection reason. As this is by far my most common reason of selecting custom, I suggest that "changed the post to the worse" should be a separate option for rejecting a suggested edit.

Comment: I'm getting more and more tempted to actually tick vandalism for random word highlighting and things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are too many rejection reasons already... I'd rather not have any more.

*Most* people seem to tick "too minor".

> [image]

I've taken to using "custom" with this message:

> Please do *not* randomly highlight random words. See
>   [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back)

Don't forget there's another option. You can <kbd>Improve</kbd> the post and uncheck the "Suggest Edit was Helpful option".

Comment: We have just enough reasons, true. As for improve, it's a real headache as you are faced with the wreck left by the edit suggestion and need to clean it yourself, maybe opening the original version in different tab. Too much hassle, better wait until the edit is rejected (hopefully) and then make your edit on clean canvas. :-)

Comment: Or more likely rollback the previous edit and then do it @sha :-).

Comment: If it's too many reasons, maybe removing the 'copied content' option is a good idea? I've reviewed 1000 suggested edits, and never seen copied content in an edit (I've seen it in new posts, but never as an edit).

Comment: Aleksander, I've rejected copied content a good deal. It is almost always on tag edits, where people plagiarise the corresponding Wikipedia entry without giving credit.

Comment: Guess I know who to blame for the downvotes I'm getting on my question today.

Comment: You've already got a gold badge @bolt; you'll survive :-).

Comment: Depending on the character of the change, I've ticked "Too minor" for things like this (fixing formatting while leaving significant grammar, punctuation and/or spelling errors; "too minor" to me implies that the edit fell short of the work the post needed) and "invalid edit" for others (i.e. introducing grammatical errors while "cleaning up formatting"; this reads "invalid" as "incorrect"). "Improving" has, a few too many times, led to my changes being rejected because the original edit was approved by others before I finished improving.

Answer (score 2):

'Vandalism' isn't the only rejection reason listed by that radio option, there is also *`defaces the post in some way`*. Incorrectly formatting, new spelling mistakes and incorrect code tagging all count as 'defacing' in my book - even if it is done with the best intentions. In any case it is certainly *`otherwise inappropriate`*.

[image]:

Comment: This post disagrees with you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137231/190750 it says that 'vandalism is malicious'.