# Bug with ads on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising

I noticed a bug/problem with a certain type of ad that appears on Stack Overflow. This occurs on Firefox, Google Chrome, and Internet Explorer, but I am not sure of any others.

Here are two different ads from Firefox and Google Chrome (Internet Explorer is like the second one, but not as bad):

> [image]

As you may or may not see, the tags under the job descriptions are too high up, cutting off the caption above a little. It only seems to occur with ads of this type.

Also, with the second ad, it seems like text is cut off at the left. The thrid ad is also from Firefox, about a day later.

Comment: It's taking the information from http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ so adding the tag.

Comment: 16 new questions in the time it took to take those two screenshots... damn... SO is popular...

Comment: Hmm.. after 20 reloads can't get any of those two, guess they took them down for now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - This ad still shows up(with the same mistake as above), but it is fairly rare.

Comment: The second add seems to be cut off at *both* sides, actually.

Comment: Who knows, maybe the companies did this on purpose so as to get more eyeballs on their ads when this Meta discussion appeared...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Thought we took care of this last week, but I guess not.

Comment: @rossipedia You are very welcome. I also just noticed something strange in my profile page. How come it says **`1 years, 1 months`** instead of **`1 year, 1 month`**? This occurs on both my MSO and SO accounts.

Comment: @s0d4pop It has always said that, I figured it was done out of simplicity. It is going to bug me now :(

Comment: @AustinHenley - Hmm, just seems strange to me. Why was I downvoted for reporting a bug?

Comment: @s0d4pop I didn't vote on the question.

Comment: @s0d4pop [Be careful pointing out pluralisation bugs.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20684/223030)

Comment: @s0d4pop it shouldn't say that (It should say "1 year"). Can you please post that as a separate question so we can track and address it?

Comment: @rossipedia - Are you sure? I thought pluralization 'bugs' were frowned upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug we're working out with how the Careers Ad CSS conflicts with the Stack Overflow CSS. Should be handled by the end of the day.

Comment: Alright, the ads on Stack Overflow are fixed now.