# Merge "unicoin" and "unicoins" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, meta, unicoins

Because unicoins are a long-term addition to Stack Exchange, I think that we should nip this issue in the bud before it gets out of control.

Can we merge [unicoin](/questions/tagged/unicoin) with [unicoins](/questions/tagged/unicoins), please? I believe the proper term is [unicoins](/questions/tagged/unicoins). Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, both tags have questions associated with them. That is not a duplicate.

Comment: This sounds good, but the tag wiki for [unicoins] is wrong. It says they are a *mythical* monetary unit, when clearly they are for reals.

Comment: @BlueIce: Are you certain you are checking the right site?

Comment: [Not directly related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20684/173052) but, it is related due to `s` (: Call Jeff, We got an `s` victim

Comment: @Geobits Tag wiki edit coming right up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The question got edited for meta tags- I meant meta tags in the first place.

Comment: @BlueIce: Yet on Meta, there are 0 questions with the `unicoin` tag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well then. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I retagged them, after I have read this post.

Comment: @Antony Aha! I knew somebody did that :)

Comment: @Antony: You've not been the only one keeping that tag clean though :-)