# Change "1 views" to "1 view" in the profile page on a newly asked question

Tags: bug, views, plurals, activity

In the "Questions" tab under the "Activity" tab on my profile, I noticed that on a newly asked question there was the following information:

> 0 answers 0 votes 1 views

Can the pluralization be corrected to show "1 view" instead of "1 views"?

---

Not a duplicate of ["viewed 1 times"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20683/986753), since that was observed on a site's "Questions" page.