# Closed as an exact duplicate ... Possible Duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wording of “possible/exact duplicates” when closing the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/wording-of-possible-exact-duplicates-when-closing-the-question)

A question is closed as an **exact** duplicate, but the duplicate is a **possible** duplicate. Isn't it strange?

> That's because until the question is closed by five users, it is only a possible duplicate. If five users have voted to close it, it is a proven duplicate.

But when 5 users voted and the question is closed on the top of question there is an inscription, **"Possible Duplicate"**.

**Example**

> [How to display ages instead of dates of birth, in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613410)

Comment: ​pos​sible dup​licate o​f [Wording of "poss​​ible/ex​act dupli​cates" when clo​sing the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/wording-of-possible-exact-duplicates-when-closing-the-question)

Comment: @YOU, haha :) funny

Comment: **Please reopen and close as duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/wording-of-possible-exact-duplicates-when-closing-the-question to update the header**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It's *possibly* an exact duplicate.

Comment: Is it possible that possible duplicate is possibly exact duplicate while it closed as an exact duplicate and still just bossible duplicate. Impossible.

Comment: @fl00r even if five people vote for it to be a duplicate, that doesn't necessarily mean it *is* one. Happens all the time. I think the choice of wording is good.

Comment: But why does it closed as an __EXACT__ duplicate while it is still __POSSIBLE__ :)

Comment: @fl00r it makes sense IMO: "I, the user, think this is an exact duplicate". It doesn't automatically mean I'm right, though. So it's a "possible exact duplicate". If it weren't an *exact* duplicate, SO's rules say it shouldn't be closed. That's why the word is there

Comment: @Pekka: The thing I don't understand is: Why does it say "Possible Duplicate" at the top of this very question, but "closed as exact duplicate" at the bottom?

Comment: @Hendrik *that* indeed doesn't make sense, you're right. It should say "possible" on both counts

Answer (score 2):

That's because until the question is closed by five users, it is only a *possible* duplicate. If five users have voted to close it, it is a *proven* duplicate.

Comment: But on the top of CLOSED question written: __"Possible duplicate"__

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm thinking that after the first user says a question it isn't that hard to find 4 more to jump on the band wagon without thinking.  There does not seem to be a way for people to disagree with a question being a duplicate.  I have seen many where looking at the possible duplicate linked, the question may cover some of the same ground, but is not the same question.  Quite often the different part is answered in comments on the duplicate question.  Still it seems like some people are in a hurry to close questions for some reason for being a duplicate...