# Inconsistency between "Possible Duplicate:" header and "Closed as exact duplicate" footer

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Ironically, take a look at this question:

[Closed as an exact duplicate ... Possible Duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87104/closed-as-an-exact-duplicate-possible-duplicate)

Why does the header of a closed duplicate question say "**Possible Duplicate:**" when the footer says "**Closed as exact duplicate**"?  If the question gets the 5 votes and is closed, can we change the header to say "**Exact Duplicate:**" instead?  It's a little confusing the way it is right now.

Either that, or include the link the the duplicate question in the footer.  For example: "**Closed as exact duplicate of [link] by [....]**".

Comment: I think a better solution would be simply to remove the word "Exact".  I think it conveys an overly-strong "exactness" that isn't always present.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate, but a solution hasn't really been addressed in the linked duplicate question.  Does this mean that nothing is going to happen, that it'll be left as-is?  I personally like animuson and Flimzy's solution.

Comment: Perhaps someone should propose that as a solution on the duplicate question linked above?

Comment: Oh...the irony......this post listing a possible duplicate and closed as exact duplicate =)

Answer (score 5):

I agree that this is a bit confusing, but changing it to "exact duplicate" is a bad move in my opinion. Especially considering you can have any number of links in that box. I'd rather leave the "possible duplicate" part in the box at the top, and just get rid of the word "exact" in the close reason at the bottom.