# Closed questions shouldn't be allowed to be "Possible Duplicates"

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Occasionally (frequently?) I see a question that is closed as a duplicate.  Since it's new to me, and I don't know what the original answer was, I follow the link...

...only to find out that *that* question was also closed as a duplicate — but, sadly, the third question is related to the second in a different way than the first was (don't pull out the pitchforks, I'm not [questioning the wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/wording-of-possible-exact-duplicates-when-closing-the-question)!)

Here is a scientific diagram of this condition:
[image]

Sometimes the actual *open* answer has been more than two questions away.  The further away it is, the worse the problem gets, like a possible-duplicates [game of "Telephone/Chinese Whispers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers).  Sometimes you end up realizing there's not actually an answer to the new question that is now closed.

Is it possible to require questions in the duplicate close-reason to actually be *open* (or at least closed for a *different* reason?

---

<sup>*I did search for a duplicate of this one, but I realize how ironic it could end up being...*</sup>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dont close questions as duplicate if the original is closed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50507/dont-close-questions-as-duplicate-if-the-original-is-closed)

Comment: @YOU - Ironic indeed, as that question is referring to sort of an inverse case.

Comment: Imm, both looks same concept to me. but no worries, if others does not agree, this will not get closed.

Comment: @YOU - I'm glad you found the link - but it's a great example of a case where it is similar and could make this a duplicate, but then a future question might be more similar to this one than that one.

Comment: @Renesis, if that future question is similar to this question than original question, I would vote to close as possible duplicate to this, instead of original. Any problem with that logic?

Comment: @YOU - that's what the question is about.  By that time, this question is closed, but the new one is not really answered.

Comment: @Renesis, so what will be the solution for that? Isn't that "[Dont close questions as duplicate if the original is closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50507/dont-close-questions-as-duplicate-if-the-original-is-closed)" in my possible duplicate link?

Comment: There are also questions out there that are closed as duplicates of deleted posts.  There were quite a few closed as dupes of the original [Eeeek! question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope) (10k only).

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram implies that some questions are being closed as ***exact duplicates*** when they are not ***exact*** duplicates.  If they were indeed exact duplicates, the circles would all be the same.  The solution seems to be for people to understand that the word ***exact*** does not mean ***similar***.  It frustrates me greatly when I see similar questions that are clearly not ***exact*** duplicates closed as such, and this potentially leads to the situation you described.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to tell what makes a duplicate ***exact***, but my criteria is usually if the two questions have the same answer. This can lead to non-exact duplicate *questions* being closed, but it avoids duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is nice, but some examples would be a lot better.  I don't think this is a problem that's widespread enough to warrant a change.  You can already vote to reopen, leave comments on, and flag posts for moderator attention if they're closed incorrectly.

Also...

> Is it possible to require questions in the duplicate close-reason to actually be open (or at least closed for a different reason?

Closed for a different reason is enough to break chains, so that's what I'd recommend if this got implemented.