# "please ask another question" in duplicate banner

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

[image]

Shouldn't the "please ask a new question" be "edit your question to make the differences clear"? That's what the established process has been for a while now -- "don't repost closed questions; edit them till we tell you what's acceptable"

The current wording seems like it would lead to a chain of dupes (till the OP finally "gets it right").

Comment: [My thoughts exactly...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166514/does-the-change-in-exact-duplicate-wording-imply-a-shift-in-policy#comment487530_166514)

Comment: I'd prefer something like "please ask a new question _or_ edit your question to make the differences clear" - a canned message would better be broad enough to avoid pushing for an action that might be wrong in specific context

Comment: @gnat: At least 9 times out of 10, asking a new question will result in a slap on the wrist and a question marked as duplicate of the original one.

Comment: @gnat: have any counterexamples? I'd rather not encourage reposting, it's harder to keep track, and can be a bit of a pain. (I've already had to deal with a few stubborn users who keep reposting the same question).

Comment: @Manishearth sure no problem; I am referring specifically to the case when _existing answers effectively lock things from substantial editing: "Change the question, and you invalidate all of the answers"_ ([one example is dicussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144787/165773))