# Is it alright to close questions which are not exact duplicates of another question, but essentially the same?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

So I recently closed a question as a duplicate: [Can't access constructor after assigning prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26359439/783743). Because I have a gold JavaScript badge I was able to arbitrarily mark the aforementioned question as a duplicate.

Now with great power comes great responsibility. A [fellow StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) pointed out that I shouldn't have marked the question as a duplicate because it isn't an exact duplicate of the other question.

However my understanding is that if a question is essentially the same as another question (ignoring a few minor differences) then it should be marked as a duplicate.

To summarize the above question, the OP asked why `george.constructor` is not `Human` when:

```
monkey = { ... };
Human.prototype = monkey;
var george = new Human("George");
```

To summarize the question that I marked it as a duplicate of, the OP asked why `(new b).constructor` is not `b` when:

```
b.prototype = new a;
```

Both these questions are structurally the same:

1. The `prototype` of some constructor is being set to some other value.
2. An instance of the new prototype is being created.
3. The OP is asking why the `constructor` property of the instance doesn't point to the original constructor.

So my question is, “was I correct in closing the above question as a duplicate?” The two questions aren't exact duplicates. Nevertheless they are essentially the same. According to Jeff Atwood ([Dr. Strangedupe](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)) duplication should be allowed if there's some variation. However too much duplication is bad.

My dilemma is:

1. Although there is some variation in the question, yet it is essentially the same as the older question.
2. How does one decide when one question has too many duplicates?

Comment: I just realized that I should have posted this on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217406/165773)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think a question is a duplicate vote appropriately, regardless of whether you can wield the gold dupe hammer or not. If people disagree they can vote to reopen or take it the site's child meta for discussion.

If you think it might not be clear why it's a duplicate then add a comment explaining your reasoning.

To answer your second point:

> 2. How does one decide when one question has too many duplicates?

A question can't have too many duplicates, though perhaps we should be looking at rephrasing the question so that it comes up in more searches.