# Can we have an option to disable notifications on community wiki posts?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, community-wiki

Please could we have a way to disable notifications on CW posts?

If I post a CW answer, (especially on meta) it is almost certainly because I want others to edit content into it. This means me getting 2 notifications a day is redundant and a little annoying.

When we make a CW post, please could we have the option to disable notifications on it?

I'm imagining something like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Maybe the notifications checkbox only appears when you tick the CW one, or it could be available for any question.

Comment: This seems to be a nice dual for [my suggestion to allow editors to sign up for CW notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181511/promote-the-collaborative-wiki-style-aspect-of-stack-exchange-more/261069#261069).

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Hopefully [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!

This really does make a lot of hassle, especially when you want the post to be edited. Sure, I guess at the end of the day, there could be one notification saying something like:

> Your post has been edited __ number of times. Check out what the community has added to the post!

`__` could represent the number of edits made on the CW post. The community wiki posts can sometime get a very high number of edits, making it a hassle for those people trying to manage multiple accounts. One notification is good enough... No one needs 20 of them.

The notifications check box could and should be applied. Some people can handle all the traffic, but some people have too much traffic to handle. Great feature-request, so it's a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)  for me! Of course, the mods decide...

Comment: I did think of the "once a day" think, but I worried that people would want to personalise it... (i.e. every 2 days, or each week)

Comment: @Tim as a workaround, you could subscribe to the post's RSS feed, and configure whatever RSS reader you use to notify you however often you want.