# How do I monitor the comments of a specific interesting question or answer (not mine)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I've found an interesting question which I presume will have activity in the future (new answers and comments to existing answers), which I will find very useful.

However, if I simply "Star" the question, I don't think I get notified for comments (on the question itself or on the answers).

1. Is there a way to monitor a SO question for new answers and get a notification?
2. Is there a way to monitor the comments of an existing answer to a SO question (not posted by me, but found interesting by me)?

I think the first one is already present (if you star a question you get notifications for new answers to that question, right?), but the second would be a very useful addition - if added.

Comment: See [my suggestion for ways to wikifiy SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181511/promote-the-collaborative-wiki-style-aspect-of-stack-exchange-more/261069#261069) for a feature request along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is currently no way to receive updates on comments. They don't even appear in the question feed. (The updates on questions and answers are available indeed starring the question or subscribing to the question feed)

Comments are second-class citizen. They are temporary pieces of information. For the main sites I don't see much use in keeping track of comments.

This could be more useful on meta posts where there are often quite long comment threads, but I do wonder if we would really want this. I don't really see the added value of notifications on comments.

Comment: For dealing with a multi-user discussion about correctness of an answer or whether a question should be closed, I don't see any way to avoid the necessity of this. At present you pretty much have to manually check back at intervals.