# Too broad - pro/cons, who's interests does the rule serve?

Tags: discussion, rules, too-broad

I remember reading old-seasoned advise about posting questions on discussion groups -  use we search before posting.  And I agree with the pro of the rule is that valuable experts time is saved.

On the downside,  a person is pushed to use non-peer-reviewed sources,  not e.g. Stackoverflow.com,  which Is kind of peer-reviewed.

Why not make stackoverflow.com single point of knowledge,  to use pro and diminish con by say feature to flag question as broad for those who consider it important,  but allow it to be valid?

Added:

1. for those who believe meta site is not for discussions,  look at tags!
2. I searched meta for questions on too-broad: found only about how to apply the rule,  not reasons for the rule.

Comment: By not catering for everyone  and everything the Q/A format is successful. We don't need nor intend to be a one-stop shop. The focus is key.

Comment: @rene, is it written clearly somewhere like mission statement?

Comment: Yes, in the tour: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour *This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.* Also relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77825/158100

Comment: @rene, your first link says meta is to discuss how sites work,  specific questions on overflow is exactly that and I want a discussion here about it. Here we even have discussion tag which I used.

Comment: [Meta is different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) ... but the tour is basically the same everywhere https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 6):

Well there's a few things. Having scattered questions of variable quality on the same issue means it's harder not easier for people to find answers.

If you find an answer before even asking a question, you basically saved a bunch of time and effort. This can be literally as simple as typing your question into a search engine and looking at what you get

Doing your homework and researching means you're closer to an answer even if you don't find one and you can ask a better question.

So practically, if you're willing to put in some effort - you benefit by learning by researching, folks can write better more focused answers and other people with the same issue can find the answer already there.

So pretty much everyone benefits.

Comment: How your answer relates to too broad issue I raised?  IMHO it upholds my case more then dismisses it.

Comment: @ChildDetektiv The point is, everyone seems to be moving in the direction of trying to be everything, but you can either strive to be multipurpose *suboptimally*, or serve a single purpose as best as you can. It's a dichotomy, and the community is in favor of trying to do a great job at one thing instead.

Comment: @M.A.R, what peer-curated site for general software questions do you advice?

Comment: @ChildDetektiv I don't know of any. Sorry.