# What happened to the SE Euler Diagram?

Tags: discussion, tour

At the beginning of this year, there was a major change in the `/about` pages for all (at least the ones that I frequent) SE sites.  However, I've noticed that we no longer sport the SE <strike>Venn</strike> Euler diagram:

[image: SE Venn]

Was there a particular reason that we abandoned displaying this?  I actually found it rather informative to point to new users when explaining what we are.

Comment: Just to be pedantic it's a [Euler Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram)

Comment: ["Venn Diagram" on SE About pages is not actually a Venn diagram](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71905/venn-diagram-on-se-about-pages-is-not-actually-a-venn-diagram)

Comment: Well, it's still the cover picture of the [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage) :)

Comment: Just to be pedantic it's _an_ Euler Diagram ;)

Comment: @acheong87: Yeah, I'd disagree. "Euler" starts with a hard "Y" sound, so "a" would be the proper indefinite article. </pedant>

Comment: @AlEverett If you mispronounce the German name, that is indeed the case. ;)

Comment: @Bart: Hey! I'm a Merkin! Don't tell me how to pronounce a German name!

Comment: I'm really confused; how does Euler sound in American? I would pronounce Euler, Oiler (assuming you'd pronounce that the same as me!), unlike other words starting with _eu_ like, for instance, eucalyptus, which is pronounced ucalyptus @AlEverett.

Comment: I've always pronounced and heard it as `You-Ler` whether right or wrong.

Comment: Pronounced [oi-ler; German, Swedish oi-luhr](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/euler)

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/De-Leonard_Euler.ogg

Comment: I'm with KronoS. 'Round these parts, it'd be pronounced YOOler.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "Oiler" - I had a Math Professor who'd studied in Germany, and insisted that was the correct pronunciation.  Also: `English: /ˈɔɪlər/, similarly to 'oiler'`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler

Comment: Yooler, Oiler, Potaito, Potahto, doesn’t matter.  This is a Venn diagram anyway. The Euler diagram wouldn’t have the empty areas.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do not be alarmed - there is a "secret" way you can see the existing SE Venn Euler diagram in its full glory.  It requires a little bit of inspection, but it's there.  Kudos goes to the first person to find this hidden gem.

Comment: I think I figured it out, but it looks like it won't work on Chrome :S

Comment: @Manishearth nope, it works in chrome

Comment: Too easy. up up down down left right left right B A enter.

Comment: Just got it!!!! I was looking at the iphone code and wondering how to make it happen without a touch device :P Didn't notice the `pattern`. Great easter egg! :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Damn you, wizard!

Comment: @Manishearth yep, it's just a Konami code. [See it in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YJE6JDUdIM) :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I figured that out long ago. Just didn't figure out that I had to hit enter -- on the iPhone you have to enter the Konami code by tapping/dragging.

Comment: @Manishearth wait?! You can do it on the iPhone?

Comment: @KronoS: tap-drag up, tap-drag up (,down,down,left,right,left,right), and then tap thrice.

Comment: @Manishearth you're iWizard!

Comment: @Geoff now where's my secret badge? :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd badge?  who said anything about a badge, but Kudos to you.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas just kidding of course. :)

Comment: TL is disappointed by the easter egg. Could it be made [awesomer?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9228485#9228485)

Comment: @Manishearth I can't get it to work on my iPhone... I thinking you're lying ;P

Comment: @KronoS: When you move up you need to make sure you move more up than right/left (et cetera)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, I believe the explanation is in [this answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164779/152859).

While no direct reference to that diagram, he does explain the main goal was to keep the new About page short and clear. The diagram was "nice to have" but not enough to justify adding it on top of the About page in addition to the short description of what Stack Overflow is.

Just my personal impression, hopefully Shog9 himself will give a better answer. :)