# 1 kviews—shouldn't kviews be singular?

Tags: discussion, plurals

It's 1 vote, 1 view, yet 1 kviews?
One wouldn't say one kilotons, or one kilobytes.

Is there any logical reason for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, in this case I think it's fine. Because unlike "kilobyte", "kiloview" isn't really a word, I read "kviews" as "thousand views", so "1 kview" would feel wrong to me.

I won't comment on other singular/plural issues, because I like being alive.

Comment: You don't want your computer getting a little "package" if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 15):

Quoting [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694):

> ## Dear Next Person Who Opens a
>   Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally
>   come to your house and bludgeon you to
>   death with a giant S

Comment: fortunately for oKtosiTe, this is a [discussion]!

Comment: @Jeff saved by a tag

Comment: @abel You mean 1 tags

Comment: If I would have read that, I might have made sure to wear a helmets.

Comment: @oKtosiTe, Giant S-es are immune for helmets. Especially if wielded by someone with a high geek factor.

Comment: Jeff is probably just as tired of seeing this quote as he is of seeing pluralization bugs

Comment: @Michael His fault :)

Comment: @Michael So the next time it will read, **"Dear Next Person Who Quotes My Pluralization Bug Threat,..."**