# Spelling: "what is a trusted users?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

On the [trusted users info page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) there is a tiny typo:

> What is a trusted users?

This of course should say "What is a trusted user?"

Comment: My vote goes to "What are a trusted users?"

Comment: @Shog9 Do you mean "What are trusted users?" - or maybe even "Who are trusted users?" though these of course have two different meanings.

Comment: @Ricket: I'm joking - replacing one bug with another.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry! Didn't recognize it as a joke, especially with the upvotes I was scared people didn't recognize the typo :)

Comment: @Ricket: no worries - I'm guessing (hoping!) the up-voters are familiar with my habit of failing to call out jokes!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791

Comment: Better: "Where are the trusted user?" adn: "Can I haz cheezeburger?"

Comment: Flagged for moderator to close; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be updated in a build going out this afternoon (~2 hours from now).

Comment: Since it's done, it should be made the accepted answer, shouldn't it?