# Where's the exclamation point after "Jeopardy" in the FAQ?

Tags: bug, status-completed

It's part of the name of the show, after all:

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!`

I feel the exclamation-point shaped hole in my soul every time I read the FAQ.

Feel free to close if you care nothing of my torment.

**Edit:** Suggested wording:

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on *Jeopardy!* and phrase it in the form of a question.

Comment: I wonder if punctuation bugs hold the same esteem with Jeff as pluralization bugs - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: Horrible error.  This should be fixed with the utmost urgency!

Comment: As long as we're being pedantic, we *really* ought to italicize it as well.

Comment: @Daniel: I guess it does speak to the level of polish the sites have now.  Pluralization errors, punctuation inconsistencies, etc., are minor errors indeed.  But this is part of the "spit and polish" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/code-its-trivial.html of the site, and it contributes to the user experience as a whole.  Truth be told, I'll still spend time on SO if my request goes by the wayside, but why bother building a Ferrari if you're going to let one slip through that has the hood ornament on backwards?

Comment: I'm not sure this even deserves a [bug] tag

Comment: @Michael:  Well, I had to choose one of the four mandatory tags.  The [feature-request] tag wasn't really appropriate.  I did get a small amount of [support], I suppose, but make this a point of [discussion]?  Just like the company Yahoo!, Inc.,  has an exclamation point, the show *Jeopardy!* has one as well.  That leaves me with [bug].

Comment: @Michael it deserves an [egregious-bug] and [top-priority] tag

Comment: @John, it's important to remember that the importance is a factor of visibility as well.  A missing exclamation point on the FAQ next to already-present punctuation (a colon, the most similar mark to an exclamation point), is really not the same level of visibility as a Ferrari with the hood ornament on backwards.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the phrase should be in there at all. The first time I read it, I had to go and google what Jeopardy was. Apart from it being a game show, I'm still not sure.

Comment: Even more, @Farseeker, [Jeopardy!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!) *"has a unique answer-and-question format in which contestants are presented with clues in the form of answers, and must phrase their responses in question form."* ⸘How does that relate to SE‽

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't in good conscience have people going around with exclamation-mark shaped holes in their souls, now can we?

Answer (score 4):

I am officially boycotting Stack Overflow until this is fixed.

Comment: Oh, it's too late for a simple fix. I expect some sort of public apology, and perhaps a few hundred rep in compensation