# Casing on vote totals is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-count, markdown

[image: "Day" versus all the rest]

Why is "Day" capitalized and the rest is all lowercase?

<sub>[Please don't bludgeon me to death with a caps lock key](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no good reason for you, but it's fixed it the next build!