# Typo in Area 51 FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, spelling

When I noticed the below typo, I had a thorough look through the complete FAQ text, but it remained the only typo I could find.

In section **What is reputation?**

```
- After a proposal enteres the beta phase, (..)
+ After a proposal enters the beta phase, (..)
```

Comment: Be aware, you might [have company soon...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694).

Comment: Good thing it was the "e" not the "s". Otherwise, [Jeff would come after you](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105).

Comment: Whatever, this earned me a Quorum badge. My life is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks a lot.