# A couple of typos on the usage page for users/{id}/tags/{tags}/top-answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, stackapps

On [this page](http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-top-tagged-answers):

> "...the top 30 answer a user has posted in resposne to..."

...should probably read:

> "...the top 30 answer**s** a user has posted in respons<s>n</s>e to..."

<sub>* Note the pluralization of 'answer' and the spelling correction of 'response'.</sub>

Comment: As you might have guessed, I'm doing some very comprehensive research on the API that has me carefully reading everything.

Comment: You might want to check the parameter descriptions while you're at it. I think `delimitted` should be `delimited` for the `tags` parameter.

Comment: [Run.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Fixed.