# Wording of Convention Badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, wording

The [convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) has the wording:

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta.

Does this mean that to get the badge I need 10 posts with a score of **exactly** 2 at the same time?

Should the wording be changed to something like:

> 10 posts with score of 2 **or more** on meta.

Comment: Looking at [disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) badge's description it clearly says *3 **or higher***. So I interpret convention badge  requires **exactly** 2.

Comment: @hims056 
it says 10 post on meta, can you tell me what is the post stands for?

Comment: @SumitBijvani - Post means either question or answer.

Comment: @hims056 okay and score means 2 up votes. I get it thanks

Comment: @SumitBijvani - No. Score means upvotes - downvotes. e.g. if you have 2 upvotes and 1 downvote on your post it means your post score is 1

Comment: @hims056 ohh okay got it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this mean that to get the badge I need 10 posts with a score of exactly 2 at the same time?

It means that when the task checking who gained that badge runs, you need to have 10 posts with a score of at least 2. This is not different from other badges, such as:

- [Commentator](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator)
- [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor)
- [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy)
- [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/155/electorate)
- [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question)
- [Favorite Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/33/favorite-question)
- [Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question)
- [Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader)
- [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer)
- [Stellar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question)

All the badges are assigned when a task to check who has the requirements runs. In the description for those badges, you should always add *at least* before the number they are referring too; for example, the "Strunk & White" badge is given even if, when the task runs, you have edited 84 posts.

I am not sure that adding *at least* in the description for those badges makes the description clearer, but if it is done for a badge, it should be done for the others.

Comment: I did take it to have a meaning inline with the other badges. I just think that it should be changed (if only for, as you say, consistency).

Comment: I disagree, they are different since all of them (except electorate) are like `<action><number><times or things>`, so even if you read literally you will still get them because at some point you must meet the exactly requirement (as difference of these other two descriptions)

Comment: @ajax333221 I don't see any difference, because also "left 10 comments" could be interpreted "left exactly 10 comments." Is there any reason why "with score of 2" should be an exception?

Comment: @kiamlaluno because at some point you MUST have 10 comments, but not necessarily at some point you "must" have exactly score 2 with that num of posts

Comment: @ajax333221 What happens if you wrote 9 comments, and you add two more comments before the cron task assigning the badges runs? The Commentator badge is for leaving at least 10 comments, and the Convention badge is for writing 10 posts with at least 2 points; there is no difference with that respect.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with this, the description if read literally it is ambiguous.

I doubt that modifying this particular description will lead to modify others badges description like the ones in the list of @kiamlaluno because they are like:

```
(badge): (action) (times) (things)
Commentator: Left 10 comments.
Copy Editor: Edited 500 posts.
```

So for all of them, even if you read them literally, at some point you meet the *exact* requirement and obtain the badge.

But if you read this literally:

```
Convention: 10 posts with score of 2 on meta.
```

Having the badge doesn't necessarily mean you met the *exact* requirement at some point, as you can get it without having exactly 10 posts with score of 2 (e.g you can have some of them without exactly score of 2, but with higher score than 2 and you will still get it), if they change it to `... score of 2 or more on meta.` it leaves no room for ambiguity.

Are there people who really think you have to have exactly 10 posts with score of 2? obviously not, but we should still fix this because people are getting annoyed by this. Not fixing it is like leaving "Satan" instead of "Santa" because everyone knows what the author meant.

Comment: Apply logic. It would make _no sense_ for it to mean "exactly 2" rather than "at least 2". Since lots of aspects of Stack Exchange expect people to use basic logic and / or common sense, there is no reason to change this just so people don't have to use common sense.

Comment: @agf so if there is a typo like `hte` to mean `the`, should we change it even if with little logic we know what it was meant?. Mostly, these minor edits are not to increase the people to understand the meaning, it is about not to annoy those who care it is wrong

Comment: Basically, no, we shouldn't. [Typo and pluralization bug reports are not encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694).

Comment: Don't need to change it. It's obvious. Where I come from we have a law: "if you drive 25kph over the limit you have your licence confiscated on the spot". *Obviously* this does not mean if you drive 26kph over you're safe.