# Quorum badge on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges, badge-description

The description for the Quroum badge on Stack Overflow says:

> One post with score of 2 on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Sounds to me as if I need exactly one post with precisely a score of 2.

Wouldn't this be a better description?:

> First post with a score of 2 or more on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Most badge-descriptions of also use the words "First" and "with a score of ... or more" .

EDIT:

Okay, the usage of the word "First" also causes some ambiguity. As SingerOfTheFall suggested:

> At least one post with a score of 2 or more on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: First post seems to imply that it has to be the first post you make on Meta?

Comment: I smell an attempt to get the mentioned badge! xD

Comment: @Fluffeh so you're saying that the "Excavator" badge also implies that it has to be the first post? :)

Comment: @Ruud, "First" is indeed ambiguous. "At least one post with a score of 2 or more on meta" will be better IMO

Comment: @RuudLenders No, I guess I am saying that the description for Excavator is *also* ambiguous :)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall you're right. And my attempt was successfull :D

Comment: related (but with the Convention Badge) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119343/wording-of-convention-badge/130138#130138

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Sounds to me as if I need exactly one post with precisely a score of 2

Don't you get the badge when your score becomes 2 - so (even if only momentarily) your score will be precisely 2 - even if it subsequently increases or decrease?

But maybe a +1 for being a pedantic test engineer, even though I can't yet give you a +1 here :-)

Comment: Thanks peeps... I can now :-)

Comment: True ;) But, I'm not saying that the current description is incorrect. I just pointed out that it fails to describe the badge without ambiguity ^_^

Comment: @RuudLenders - congrats on the `Nice Question` badge... feel free to mark this as your `Favourite Answer` :)