# Description of meta participation badges

Tags: feature-request, badge-description

Currently we are showing the description of meta participation badges(Convention and Quorum) as

> **Quorum**: One post with score of 2 on meta
>
> **Convention**: 10 posts with score of 2 on meta

It should be like *post with score of 2 or more* will be more apt.

[image]

We already have this wordings for many other badge descriptions.

Comment: Many badge description differ a little. If this is to be changed then please consider all badge descriptions and not just those 2.

Comment: [Quorum badge on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146918/187824). Also, [Wording of Convention Badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119343/187824)

Comment: @Mołot - That means the description of [disciplined badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) is *mathematically* wrong.

Comment: @hims056 my mistake, I misread where OP want to put "or more". I stand corrected.

Comment: And all this time I've been trying to make my meta posts mediocre so they only get 2 upvotes...