# Small grammar bug on area51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, plurals

Part of the area51 page for [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) currently reads:

> Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. We recommend:
>   150 users with 200+ rep (currently 57 users with 200+ rep)
>   10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently **1 users** with 2,000+ rep)
>   5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 0 users with 3,000+ rep)

Clearly it doesn't effect the functionality of the site, but it'd be nice if the grammar were correct - i.e. display 1 user, not users.

Comment: Quick, where's that tweet - the one about the giant 'S' ...

Comment: @AdamRackis https://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: Oh, my. Well I suppose it had to happen _one_ more time.

Comment: @AnnaLear: With Jeff's leaving SE, who will go bludgeon people now!?

Comment: @animuson That just means it is now safe to open Pluralization Bugs! (note the lack of quotes on Bug)

Comment: @animuson I suspect Shog9. He is well suited for the role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news: this is fixed now. But the bad news: preparations for your bludgeoning are underway.

Comment: I shall hide under the sofa until further notice ;)

Answer (score 8):

I refer you to the following:

http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

> ## Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

Reference [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/132480) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/132480)

<sub>The new regime might take this more seriously, however the essence of the answer remains</sub>

Comment: Well, I, for one, welcome our new Giant S overlords!

Comment: And now that Jeff is leaving, the new overlords can be trained to not dismiss these out-of-hand.

Comment: There has been no reversal of this position.  Where do you live, @berry120? :)

Comment: @Jarrod I'll create a GUI interface using visual basic to track his IP address

Comment: @DavidFullerton: **LOL!** Good one!

Answer (score 4):

Well, if we're going to nitpick the grammar, then let's fix that colon.

> [a colon] should not separate a verb from its complement or a preposition from its object.

Strunk & White pg 8

---

In other words what comes before a colon needs to be a complete sentence, which "We recommend" isn't.

So Jeff, before you pack out your office, be sure to fix the pluralization above, and also kill off that colon :-)

Comment: I can see Jeff beating someone with a giant colon, too. Careful.

Comment: @TimPost As long as he's not strangling someone with his own colon…

Comment: @Gilles Note, I said *a* colon. Ownership of said colon is at the sole discretion of the one giving the beatings. It may be his, or it may be  *your's*. Heck, it might even be 'borrowed' from an unwitting passer by.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. But if one is going to nit-pick another's grammar, best to double-check one's own:

> it'd be nice if the grammar was correct

You mean it would be nice if the grammar [**were**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English) correct. ;-) *(Ducks and runs.)*

Comment: Nicely done, TJ

Comment: I have no words.. +1 ;)

Comment: [Skitt's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skitt%27s_law) applies. But TJCrowder, you picked something that's actually not an error (thus the law applies to your post too): you don't have to use the subjunctive, the indicative is also correct. Now, @berry120, look up *affect* and *effect* in a dictionary.

Comment: @Gilles: I don't believe the indicative is correct when you're dealing with the conditional ("it'd be nice"). That's why we have the subjunctive. But I'm always open to learning, so [I've asked the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/is-the-indicative-correct-when-dealing-with-a-conditional-future). :-) (Thanks for the Skitt's Law link; of *course* there's a "law" for it.)