# Small Grammar Bug in Stackoverflow User Questions Tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, plurals

I have done some research and realized this isn't the first time:

*[Small grammar bug on area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121666/small-grammar-bug-on-area51)*
(1 *users* instead of 1 *user*)

So here you go:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ38R.jpg]

It'd be nice if the grammar were correct! :)

Comment: You'd better hide from the 'S' now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: Crap didn't see that coming!

Comment: Did Jeff hand that S over when he left?

Comment: In all seriousness, I do find correct pluralization to be a sign of attention to detail in software. The argument (or rather religious debate here) is, it's often attention to the _wrong_ details. But, good luck, and may the S be with you.

Comment: @TimPost Do those S's work like boomerangs? Differently, I imagine Stack Exchange needs to buy a new giant S every time it uses one. `;)`

Comment: @TimPost as long as it's an improvement it's not the "wrong" details, *fixing* something is never wrong and leaving something unfixed is never right, it's just a matter of priorities.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*grumble* fine!, but only because to match other places like this we already fixed it *grumble*

Answer (score 6):

Right now we have the habit of bludgeoning any pluralizsation complainer with a giant S.

This is great, but kind of messy. So I have a counter proposal:

Let anybody that wants to report a pluralization bug, bake a giant sized S shaped cake and get it to the SE team (fresh and complete).

Comment: I should take it from Italy, and USA customs would not let me take it with me.